# Are there any benefits to optimize web performace by store js in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Are there any benefits to optimize page load time by store js in localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

depends, do you have some data that you'd normally load via an ajax call and could benefit from caching in localStorage?

If you want faster page load times you could use the [html5 cache manifest](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).  When done properly your page will load instantly because all it's assets (js, css) are cached and the cached copies are used by default.